# MYSQL Joining 3 tables with one being a link table

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

You would think this would be easy to find but after a lot of searching i cannot find an example that fits, probably because im using the wrong keywords to searching. I do realize this is pretty basic but i have tried so many variations and i just cant get it and a lot of the examples im seeing have a.tablename and b.tablename which just makes it confusing, while i do intent to read up on MYSQL further as i just about know the basics im just looking to get out of a hole so i can get my current code working for now.

Here is my SQL join which miserably fails:

```
SELECT faq.faq_title
FROM faq, category
INNER JOIN faq_link_category ON faq_link_category.category_id = category.category_id
WHERE faq_link_category.category_id =6
```

Basically i have 3 tables

```
faq table
---------
faq_id
faq_title

category table
---------
category_id
category_name

faq_link_category
---------
faq_id
category_id
```

Whats happening is that each FAQ can have more than 1 category associated so i set it up this way so i could basically do a search something on the lines of:

show me all faq titles where the category = 6

but im getting like 500 results instead of 4 or 5.

in short im arriving on a page with something like this
index.php?=6

So i want to find all the faqs for that category where category_id = x which happens to be 6 in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an outer join:

```
SELECT faq_title
FROM faq f
JOIN faq_link_category flc
ON f.faq_id = flc.faq_id
JOIN category c
ON flc.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE flc.category_id = 6
```

Comment: thanks, for reference what is c,f and flc representing

Comment: You are welcome. They are just aliases to make typing shorter thus easier and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `faq`.`faq_title`
FROM `faq`
INNER JOIN `faq_link_category` ON `faq_link_category`.`category_id` = `faq`.`faq_id`
INNER JOIN `category` ON `faq_link_category`.`category_id` = `category`.`category_id`
WHERE `faq_link_category`.`category_id` = 6
```